# Adding a service reference in VS2012 does not update the web.config

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I add a service reference in Visual Studio 2012 nothing happens to my Web.config. The System.ServiceModel is not added if it doesn't exist nor updated if it does exist.  I have to copy/paste the settings manually from the server side to get them in my web.config.  Does anyone know why my wcf configuration isn't being pulled into the web.config when I add a service reference?  It always did this for me in previous versions of Visual Studio.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you already checked whether there are any updates to VS 2012 that might address this in case it's a bug?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution? Also when I update my web.config with a new URL and afterwards click on "Update Reference" it uses the old URL.

Also sometimes when I Configure Service Reference and enter a new URL it doesn't update old bindings, it creates a new one, and when I start my application I get an error saying that there are two of the same endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but then found this blog post and it helped: http://thomashundley.com/post/2011/12/07/WCF-Service-References-not-generating-webconfig-client-endpoints-and-bindings.aspx - basically, in the Service Reference advanced configuration, clean up the list of assemblies that are checked - only leave the ones that you are sure are needed for types used in the service.

Comment: The link is dead